# Could not deduce SingI of predecessor Nat

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, singleton-type, curry-howard

I am trying to write a `weaken` function for finite sets of integers. I am using the `singletons` package. I have defined and promoted addition, subtraction and predecessor functions, as well as proved some equations on them to help the type-checker. But the error I am getting is quite unrelated to all that.

```
weaken :: forall n m k . (SingI n, SingI m, SingI k, (Minus m n) ~ NatJust k) => Fin n -> Fin m
weaken ZF =  gcastWith (apply Refl $ plus_minus sm sn sk) ZF
  where sn = sing :: SNat n
        sm = sing :: SNat m
        sk = sing :: SNat k
weaken (SF n) = gcastWith (apply Refl $ succ_pred sm) (SF (weaken n))
  where sn = sing :: SNat n
        sm = sing :: SNat m
        sk = sing :: SNat k
```

The error I am getting is on the recursive call of `weaken` (`SF (weaken n)`) and is the following: `Could not deduce (SingI n1)`, where `n1` is correctly inferred to be the type-level predecessor of type `n`. I *could* add a `SingI (Pred n)` constraint but this simply moves the problem one level down (GHC now says it can't deduce the equivalent of `(SingI (Pred (Pred n)))`).

How can I convince GHC that `SingI (Pred n)` follows from `SingI n` (and why doesn't the `singletons` package already do this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GHC.TypeLits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html), which ultimately provides us type-level non-negative `Integer`-s, exports no functions that would let us do singleton runtime operations. For example, given `KnownNat a` and `KnownNat b`, there is no standard function to produce `KnownNat (a + b)` at runtime.

`singletons` solves this by implementing the [singleton `Nat` operations](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.2/docs/src/Data-Singletons-Prelude-Num.html#line-85) unsafely.

`singletons` subtraction function throws an error for negative results (and doesn't truncate to 0 as we'd wish), so we can't reuse that for `pred` and have to implement it ourselves:

```
{-# language TypeApplications #-} -- plus all the usual exts

import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits
import Unsafe.Coerce

type family Pred (n :: Nat) :: Nat where
  Pred 0 = 0
  Pred n = n :- 1

sPred :: Sing n -> Sing (Pred n)
sPred sn = case fromSing sn of
  0 -> unsafeCoerce (sing @_ @0)
  n -> case toSing @Nat (n - 1) of
    SomeSing sn -> unsafeCoerce sn
```

You can use `sPred` to get `Sing (Pred n)`, then `withSingI` or `singInstance` to convert that into `SingI (Pred n)`.

However, you probably shouldn't use `SingI` in `weaken`. The purpose of `SingI` is to plug around singleton parameters automatically in contexts where you don't use them for anything besides forwarding them to other functions. Instead just use `Sing`, and you can avoid `sing` and type annotation noise. In my experience `Sing` is preferable to `SingI` in about 90% of the time for `singletons` programming.